# Database not created after spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

Tags: hibernate

Database not created after spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create in application.properties.

This is my application.properties's code

```
# suppress inspection "UnusedProperty" for whole file

# Spring
spring.profiles.active=dev

# Server
server.port=8080
server.sessionTimeout=30

# JPA
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update -


# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Tomcat
tomcat.accessLogEnabled=false
tomcat.protocolHeader=x-forwarded-proto
tomcat.remoteIpHeader=x-forwarded-for
tomcat.backgroundProcessorDelay=30


# Connection url for the database "taskmanager"
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/medooldoctor
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medooldoctor
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
#postgres
spring.datasource.password = root
#postgres

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Pretty-print JSON responses
spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
```

After this, when i run the command "show databases;" in terminal, no database is created .....what should i do then?

Comment: It will not create the database it will only create the tables. The database already has to exist.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate wont create the database: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` means that every deployment hibernate must delete all tables if they exist and recreate them .. it is used for development phase, so in your case you specified that your database name is **medooldoctor** `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medooldoctor` .. hibernate will try to generate your schema inside this data base but it wont create it.. So You will have to access phpmyadmin module and create a database manually with the name medooldoctor